# How do I take a snapshot using cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I'd just like to take a restorable snapshot of my data (so I can revert if I break anything). I don't want to actually download the data (so then have to reupload it). By snapshot I'm talking much like a ZFS snapshot. Can I do this with `cpanel`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restores full account backup then you will have to contact your hosting provider for this. They will restore it for you, With the cpanel access you can not restore full account backups.

Answer (score 0):

Two of the hosting companies I've used had integrations with CPanel that did automated backups and also had a button I could click to do my own backups on-demand.

My current provider has two different backup options.  One built-in to CPanel, and one is a 3rd-Party add-in called R1Soft.  R1Soft does a live backup of the Database Tables too, I think that's similar to the goals of ZFS.

[image]

[image]